# Not sure how to add parameters to a NetBiter EC310

Tags: logging, parameters, ethernet, plc, s7-1200

I've just purchased a NetBiter EC310 and I'm having trouble adding parameters to the template.

The PLC(Siemens S7-1200) and Netbiter are connected over Ethernet/IP and working.

To add a parameter the following form needs to be filled in:

[image: Add parameter]

The DataBlock of the parameters:

[image]

What should i fill in the form to add for example "bool1"?

Hoping someone got some knowledge about this product.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if anyone on this site can answer because this is a question about a specific PLC model. I suggest looking up any documentation online for that specific PLC. Sorry I can't be of help.

Comment: You have selected Ethernet/IP in your window.
That sounds more like Allen Bradly.
Can you also select something like Siemens S7 protocol or Profinet?